# edit in detailsview with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am fairly new at ASP.NET c#.  I would like to edit a detailsview with a dropdown list.  I have followed the instructions on this link -- [This link](http://www.ittutorial.net/pages/tutorial-asp-net-dropdownlist-in-detailsview.html)-- and it was exactly what I orrigionally thought of. This is flawed however, because although I can see the items on my dropdown list, it does not actually update the database.  I am at a loss.  I have been trying to find an answer for a couple of days now and am unsure of what I need to do. Is there something I need to do in the backend?  I will attach my code at the end as well.  Currently I have nothing going on in the backend.

```html
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:it_supportConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [issues] WHERE [issue_id] = @issue_id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [issues] ([requestor], [email], [urgency], [issue_type], [details], [priority], [issue_manager], [status], [date_reported]) VALUES (@requestor, @email, @urgency, @issue_type, @details, @priority, @issue_manager, @status, @date_reported)" SelectCommand="SELECT issues.issue_id, issues.requestor, issues.email, issues.phone, issues.urgency, issues.issue_type_id,Issue_Type.[Issue_Type_ID], Issue_Type.[Issue_Type],  issues.details, issues.priority, issues.issue_manager, issues.status, issues.date_reported, issues.notes FROM issues LEFT OUTER JOIN Issue_Type ON Issue_Type.Issue_Type_Id = issues.issue_type_id WHERE (issues.issue_id = @issue_id)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE issues SET requestor = @requestor, email = @email, urgency = @urgency, details = @details, priority = @priority, issue_manager = @issue_manager, status = @status, date_reported = @date_reported WHERE (issue_id = @issue_id)">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="requestor" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="urgency" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="details" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="priority" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_manager" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date_reported" Type="DateTime" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="issue_id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="requestor" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="urgency" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="details" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="priority" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_manager" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date_reported" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="issue_id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:it_supportConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Issue_Type.Issue_Type_Id, Issue_Type.Issue_Type, issues.issue_type_id AS Expr1 FROM Issue_Type LEFT OUTER JOIN issues ON Issue_Type.Issue_Type_Id = issues.issue_type_id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="issue_id" HeaderText="issue_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="issue_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="requestor" HeaderText="requestor" SortExpression="requestor" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="phone" SortExpression="phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="urgency" HeaderText="urgency" SortExpression="urgency" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="issue_type_id" SortExpression="issue_type_id">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Issue_Type_Id" DataValueField="Expr1" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("issue_type_id") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("issue_type_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("issue_type_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Issue_Type" HeaderText="Issue_Type" SortExpression="Issue_Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="details" HeaderText="details" SortExpression="details" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="priority" SortExpression="priority" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="issue_manager" HeaderText="issue_manager" SortExpression="issue_manager" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date_reported" HeaderText="date_reported" SortExpression="date_reported" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="notes" SortExpression="notes" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Can you post the SqlDataSource you're using?

Comment: I added it to the code snippit